# es6 class. this.addeventlistener

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I am trying in a class to add an eventlistener but keep getting this error:

"TypeError: this.win.addEventListener is not a function"

How can i solve this?

Code:

```
class Ui {
    constructor(el) {
        this.win = $(window);
        this.onResize = this.onResize.bind(this);
        this.init();
    }

    init() {
        console.log(this.win);
        this.addListeners();
    }

    addListeners() {
        this.win.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
    }

    onResize() {
        console.log('test');
    }
}

export default Ui;
```

Comment: Why do you need to store the `window` in an instance of the class?

Comment: I don't think I see an issue with the class, how are you invoking addListeners() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery instances do not have `addEventListener` method. Use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

```
addListeners() {
    this.win.on('resize', this.onResize);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery objects are collections, we need to get the first element of that colection:

```
this.win[0].addEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
```