# es6 class variable gets undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Im currently getting into es6 and want to use the class pattern.
But how come "this.hola" is undefined in "onResize()"?

```
class Ui {

constructor() {
    this.win = $(window);
    this.hola = 'hola';
    this.init();
}

init() {
    this.addListeners();
}

addListeners() {
    this.win.on('resize load', this.onResize);
}

onResize() {
    console.log(this.hola);
}
```

}

export default Ui;

Comment: Ohh, common. You already had correct code in your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46935952/es6-class-this-addeventlistener

Comment: `this.onResize` is a function not attached to any object. It has no `this`. When it gets invoked later in response to an event, `this` is set by jQuery to the element that triggered the event. If you want to retain the value of `this`, bind the function or use the es6 "fat arrow".

Comment: replace `onResize` to `const onResize = () => {...}`

Comment: Replace this `this.win.on('resize load', this.onResize.bind(this));`

Comment: @Rajesh: Class fields are an experimental feature. No browser supports it yet. Your example would be wrong anyway since class fields are not qualified with `const`/`let` or `var`.

Comment: @FelixKling my bad. Have been working with typescript lately so got confused. Will remove it.